# Grub rescue after deleting Kali Linux partition, tried bootrec diskpart and insmod normal not working

Tags: windows-8.1, multi-boot, bootloader, kali-linux, grub2

I seek help on my issue regarding removing Kali Linux from a dual boot with Windows 8.1.

These are the steps I followed to remove Kali Linux:

1. Boot into Windows 8.1
2. Delete the Kali Linux partition
3. Extend the Windows 8.1 partition
4. Reboot

After rebooting, grub rescue appeared.

I then booted my Windows 8.1 iso via USB (Using YUMI) and ran `bootrec` command. However for:

```
bootrec /fixmbr

  successful
```

and after reboot, grub rescue was still there.

```
bootrec /fixboot

  element not found 

bootrec /rebuildbcd

  element not found
```

Then I tried to go to Diskpart and tried to set the partition to Active, but the output states that the partition is currently ACTIVE.

I even tried to command in grub rescue

```
ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos1) (hd0,msdos2) 
set boot=(hd0,msdos2)
set prefix=(hd0,msdos2)/grub/boot
isnmod normal

error: unknown filesystem

normal

Unknown command 'normal'
```

Now I can still access my Windows 8.1 after booting into Super Grub2 Disk and boot Windows 8.1, but how should I fix it or remove grub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rescatux](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/) is a free bootable live CD/USB that can repair GRUB and the Windows bootloader. Rescatux has a graphical interface with a menu of operating system rescue tasks. If your hard disk has the MBR partitioning format, you can select the *Restore Windows MBR (BETA)* option to repair the Windows bootloader.

**Boot options:**

- (>=0.41 beta 1) Update UEFI order
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Create a new UEFI Boot entry
- (>=0.41 beta 1) UEFI Partition Status
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Fake Microsoft Windows UEFI
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Hide Microsoft Windows UEFI
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Reinstall Microsoft Windows EFI
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Check UEFI Boot

**GRUB options:**

- (>=0.40 beta 11) Easy GNU/Linux Boot Fix
- Restore GRUB and GRUB2
- (>=0.31 beta 4) Update any GRUB2 menu
- Update Debian/Ubuntu GRUB menus

**Windows options:**

- Restore Windows MBR (BETA)
- Clear Windows passwords
- (>=0.31 beta 4) Promote a Windows user to Administrator role
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Reinstall Microsoft Windows EFI
- (>=0.31 beta 4) Unlock Windows user

**Password options:**

- Change GNU/Linux Password
- Regenerate sudoers file
- Clear Windows passwords

[image]
<sup>**Rescapp is a nice wizard that will guide you through your rescue tasks.**</sup>

---

#### How to make a Rescatux live USB

- From Windows

  Download [Universal USB Installer](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) (recommended at [Rescatux Wiki](http://wiki.rescatux.org/wiki/Main_Page#How_to_make_a_Rescatux_USB) ) and open the Universal USB Installer application, insert a USB flash drive, select your USB drive, and select the Rescatux iso file to write to the USB drive. Be **very careful** when you select the USB drive that you don't select one of the partitions on your hard drive by accident, which will result in overwriting all of the data on that partition and all the data that was on that partition will be lost.

  Note: If you are working with 0.30 beta 4 (or newer) version you should extract the iso which it is found inside the iso you have downloaded ( boot/boot-isos folder ) and use that instead of the downloaded iso.
- From Linux

  Follow the instructions at [How to make a Rescatux USB](http://wiki.rescatux.org/wiki/Main_Page#How_to_make_a_Rescatux_USB).

  To prevent overwriting a partition on your hard drive by accident and losing all the data on that partition, make sure you know which is your USB device before you write the Rescatux iso.

Comment: Dang, I tried to use Rescatux with Yumi (along with some other iso) before it just never work, Just now I tried to use the one you suggested [Universal USB Installer] and it work like charm lol thank you very much =)